Is there a way in knitr to add an attribute to a script tag?
I'm working in RStudio and am instructing knitr to include a JavaScript code chunk:
```{js, echo=FALSE}
import { MyModule } from './js/mymodule.js';

[other code]
 
```.

However, the JS engine is throwing an import error because I need the opening <script> tag to contain the attribute type="module". Is there a way I can have knitr automatically add this attribute for me instead of putting in by hand in the resulting HTML file?

I'd suggest that you write the <script> tag directly, since it's not much extra typing effort, and raw HTML elements work fine in Markdown.
<script type="module">
import { MyModule } from './js/mymodule.js';

[other code]
</script>


Ah, thank you! I'm obviously new to Markdown and happy to discover I was overcomplicating things.

You can blame it on me for overcomplicating the way to add JS in knitr first :)
